# What is my job title?

Tags: communication, new-job, applications, job-description, title

I recently got hired as a “Consumer Engagement Manager”. I currently create all the communication (e-marketing, social, & on the app) on a learning app while also assisting other social media projects.. My job title does not match my job duties. Any ideas what could be my job title?

Comment: I feel this question is far too broad in it's scope and isn't necessarily something where WP can add value - it sounds like you are a Marketing Manager - but then there are so many different titles for similar roles (often to differentiate and give the air of importance) that we could post a long litany of titles that could be applied.

Comment: Are you asking what your job title is (whatever the company agrees to call you) or what the name is for the role you have described?

Comment: What the name is for the role I have described.

Answer (score 7):

> I recently got hired as a “Consumer Engagement Manager”.

This is your job title. Job titles are not regulated, they're anything the company wants them to be.

I once worked at a job where everyone was a senior engineer, including the chap who just drove us around to clients.

Comment: _Some_ job titles are regulated in _some_ jurisdictions - "engineer" being a reasonably common one, particularly if you try and put "chartered" in front of it. That said, "community engagement manager" almost certainly isn't regulated.